# Can't subtract two JavaScript numbers

Tags: javascript, math, casting, int, nan

Both pos1 and pos2 are javascript numbers, yet when I subtract one from the other, I get NaN.

http://jsfiddle.net/2akeL/2/

```
var str = "2014/6/3 ";
var y = str.substr(2,2);
var pos1 = str.indexOf("/");
var pos2 = str.indexOf("/", pos1+1);
pos2 = ((pos2-pos1)==2 ? 1 : 2 );
var m = str.substr(pos1+1, pos2);
var d = str.substr(pos2+1);
var i = (m.length < 2 ? str("0") + m : m) + "/" + (d.length = 2 || "0" + d) + "/" + y + "*";
alert(pos1 + "|" + pos2 + "|" + m + "|" + pos2);
```

Comment: So debug your code by logging your values. Sometimes you just need to get your hands a little dirty.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @cookiemonster I did. pos1 is 4, pos2 is 6.

Comment: @admdrew why do I get a NaN when I subtract pos1 from pos2?

Comment: Read about operator precedence and associativity. Debugging would involve doing things like `console.log(pos2-pos1);` and seeing that it works, then trying `console.log("|" + pos2-pos1);` and seeing that it doesn't, and then deducing the likely problem from that.

Comment: @cookiemonster This doesn't work?? pos2 = ((pos2-pos1)==2 ? 1 : 2 );

Comment: @ism you should try being more explicit when describing problems than just saying something "doesn't work".  What answer do you get, and what answer did you expect?

Comment: Also the fiddle you've got up now doesn't work because there's an error reported in the console (`str("0")` is incorrect; I'm not sure what you meant that to be).

Comment: [Here is the fiddle without that "str()" error.](http://jsfiddle.net/65v36/)

Comment: @Pointy Ahhhh make that an answer and I'll pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the JavaScript rules for order of evaluation. Your alert expression is evaluated as if it were written like this:

```
alert((((((((pos1 + "|") + pos2) + "|") + m) + "|") + pos2) - pos1));
```

Thus "pos2" is appended to a string before "pos1" is subtracted. Unlike the addition operator, there are no string semantics for `-`, so the string ends up as a `NaN`.

Write that line like this:

```
alert(pos1 + "|" + pos2 + "|" + m + "|" + (pos2-pos1));
```

By parenthesizing the subtraction operation, you force that result to be computed *before* the rest of the string is constructed.

Also, your code at one point included a call to a non-existant function "str", and that was causing an error.

Comment: so now that I moved the operation out of alert... still doesn't work.

Comment: Here I was, thinking that `str("0")` is invalid, as `str` is not a function, but it probably works in old IE.

Comment: @ism in what way does it not work? What exactly did you do? Did you try simply parenthesizing the subtraction?

Comment: @Pointy the alert doesn't pop up in the new fiddle

Comment: @ism that's because of the error in your code.  See [this repaired version](http://jsfiddle.net/65v36/) where I replaced `str("0")` with just `"0"`.